# Column selection via AWK

Tags: text, awk, multiple-columns

I have a set of large txt logs which looks like

```
    0.001 +/-  0.001
   -0.001 +/-  0.001
    0.001 +/-  0.001
    0.002 +/-  0.001
    0.001 +/-  0.001
   -0.000 +/-  0.001
    0.000 +/-  0.001
    0.001 +/-  0.001
    0.003 +/-  0.002
   -0.001 +/-  0.001
```

from each of the log I need to select only 1 column, remove all gaps and print it to new txt file which for the above log should like:

```
0.001
-0.001
0.001
0.002
etc..
```

will be thankful for the 1 command suggestion (possible via AWK) how to do it

Comment: `awk '{print $1}' input_file`

Comment: lol

Comment: actual lol at the lack of effort

Answer (score 2):

To print the first column of the file, you can do:

```
awk '{print $1}' file
```

If you want to skip the last line of the file, you can store the field in
a variable, and print the previous line each time:

```
awk 'p!=""{print p}{p=$1}' file
```

Comment: thanks! What I should to add to AWK command to skip last line in each log after such processing (like reverse of what tail command is do).

Comment: @user3470313 I edited the answer to add a solution that skips the last line

Answer (score 1):

and this:

```
cut -d' ' -f1 file > newFile
```

may work too

Answer (score 1):

Using a bit of regular expressions...

```
grep -Po '^\s*\K\S*'
```

or

```
perl -nE 'say /(\S+)/'
```

Comment: Why not!  This is possibly the most basic question i have ever seen on here

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have any number whit just `0` this should do:

```
awk '$0=$1' file
0.001
-0.001
0.001
0.002
0.001
0.001
0.003
-0.001
```

If you have `0` or need a more robust version.

```
awk '{$0=$1}1' file
0.001
-0.001
0.001
0.002
0.001
0.001
0.003
-0.001
```